# How to change the upload_max_size for moodle in Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS?

Tags: 22.04, php, moodle

I am trying to change the upload_max_size for my moodle application following
[the documentation](https://docs.moodle.org/401/en/File_upload_size) but after restarting the server i receive a message that the limit is only 2MB

[php info here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvSlM.png)

[Moodle ubuntu documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPBA6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation on that Moodle site is out of date by a decade or so. In order to change the maximum upload size on an Ubuntu 22.04 system running Apache and PHP 8.1, you will want to do this:

0. Connect to your server
1. Edit the `php.ini` file for your version of PHP:

   ```
   sudo {editor of choice} /etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini
   ```

   <sup>**Note 1:** Be sure to replace `{editor of choice}` with your editor of choice.</sup>
   <sup>**Note 2:** If you are not using PHP 8.1, be sure to replace `8.1` with the version your system is using.</sup>
2. Locate the line that reads `upload_max_filesize` and change the limit to something that makes sense for your installation:

   ```
   upload_max_filesize = 64M
   ```

   *Optional:*

   If people will regularly be uploading many files at the same time, consider increasing the `max_file_uploads` value as well.
3. Given the way Moodle is designed, it may also be useful to increase the maximum size for POST requests:

   ```
   post_max_size = 16M
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** This will depend on how your students are using Moodle. Generally 16~32M is sufficient to handle anything that most plugins will expect.</sup>
4. Increase the `memory_limit` to also handle some of the less-efficient modules/plugins that are available for Moodle:

   ```
   memory_limit = 256M
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Generally 256M is sufficient for most Moodle installations. Some may require 384M if there is a remarkable amount of server-side processing going on with each HTTP request.</sup>
5. Save the `php.ini` file
6. Restart Apache:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```
7. Test your Moodle installation

Comment: i followed the steps but i dont know why the `upload_max_filesize` doesn't change. in the moodle php info it says that the limit is 2MB

Comment: I already have `post_max_size = 16M`  and `upload_max_filesize = 64M`

Comment: Are you running PHP 8.1 or a different version? Are you using a standard LAMP stack or XAMPP?

Comment: I am using LAMP also, i am using php 7.4 i went to this route to change the .ini `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini`